# Google Search Appliance not indexing

Tags: drupal, search, google-search-appliance

Not too familiar with GSA here so hopefully someone can help me.

Have a Drupal multisite installation, just added another site to it. It all works fine. However, when I go into the GSA admin, it won't crawl the site even though the URL pattern matching is fine.

All it says is this:

"/  Info: Redirected URL"

It hits the homepage and stops. Anyone know why? This GSA powers the other Drupal sites running and works just fine. I haven't any idea what would cause this, robots.txt looks fine, no redirects in the code, its using mostly the same code and modules from sites/all/modules. Puzzled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. Drupal redirect from bad path_redirect record.